# Done and dusted

Tags: meaning, etymology

I came across the idiom 'Done and dusted'. I would like to know what is the origin and meaning of this idiom.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Done and dusted**

documents were signed in times past using pens dipped in ink, drying time could be considerable as the application of the ink varied so much. **To speed things up an absorbent dust was sprinkled on the fresh writing**, left momentarily, and then tipped off the sheet, allowing the document to be rolled or folded there and then, and carried off. Thus, a deal was considered finalized when it was "done and dusted". [done and dusted](http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/54/messages/286.html)

It is used to say that something has been successfully completed.

*I hope our agreement is done and dusted sooner than we expect.*

Comment: +1 See also http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dust?q=done+and+dusted#dust__22.

Comment: You see Tywin Lannister doing this sometimes in Game of Thrones, lovely attention to detail.

Comment: There are also _blotters_ applied to just-applied ink to soak up excess. I think I last saw this on some important treaty being signed. In both cases (dust and blotter), I believe the purpose is to remove excess ink, rather than making the ink dry faster. Corrections welcome.

Comment: You missed the most important lines from your pasted text: "Anyone know the origin of the phrase 'done and dusted...? I came across this one, but can't verify." Do you have anything to help back up this claim?

Comment: @ Hogo I have found the following, hope it can help.          Origin & history
Originally because writing with a wet ink pen needs to be blotted dry, and the original blotting method was pounce powder.http://www.wordsense.eu/done_and_dusted.

Comment: In the past, everyone made use of ink to write; people dipped their quill or pen into a bottle of ink before putting words on paper. Those of us who have used a fountain pen know that ink doesn’t dry very quickly. Sometimes, you had to wait for a long time before the paper absorbed the ink. To quicken the drying process, people used to sprinkle an absorbent dust or powder on the paper. Once the ink had dried, the powder was dusted off the paper.
http://www.thehindu.com/books/know-your-english/know-your-english-what-is-the-meaning-and-origin-of-done-and-dusted/article5699834.ece

Answer (score 6):

*Done and dusted* means something is completely finished.

The first citation in the OED is in the 20th century, long after the invention of the ballpoint pen.

> 1953   *Brit. Bee Jrnl.* 15 Oct. 669/1   All to be done and dusted before the National Honey Show. After this the grand clear up.

This lends doubt to the pen-and-ink and absorbent dust origin, especially as the quoted text from the other answer misses out the [source's own doubt](http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/54/messages/286.html):

> Anyone know the origin of the phrase 'done and dusted...?
>
> I came across this one, but can't verify.

Comment: It must come from a tired housewife's expression: "Everything's done and dusted. Finally, I can enjoy a cup of tea and watch a bit of telly" :)

Answer (score 0):

Done and dusted.... comes from the chimney sweeper finishing his job ... The chimney sweeper would always bring a maid/cleaner with him and when he had swept/cleaned the chimney the room would be full of soot and the maid would clean the room. On payment the chimney sweeper would say DUN and Dusted!

Comment: Is this your supposition or did you read it somewhere?

Comment: I have never read of chimney sweeps bring a maid to clean up the ensuing soot that would fall on the floor in and around the fireplace. It is true that they would bring small children  who could climb up the narrower chimney flues. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chimney_Sweepers_Act_1788

Answer (score -1):

Akin to "dead and buried."  The funeral service is done and the dirt ("dust") has been put back into place on top of the casket (which is 'dusted').

Comment: Do you have a authoritative source for this?